# How to remove escape characters from a string in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have input string like `"\\{\\{\\{testing}}}"` and I want to remove all `"\"`. Required o/p: `"{{{testing}}}"`.

I am using following code to accomplish this.

```
protected String removeEscapeChars(String regex, String remainingValue) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(remainingValue);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String before = remainingValue.substring(0, matcher.start());
        String after = remainingValue.substring(matcher.start() + 1);
        remainingValue = (before + after);
    }
    return remainingValue;
}
```

I am passing regex as `"\\\\{.*?\\\\}"`.

Code is working fine only for 1st occurrence of "\{" but not for all its occurrences.
Seeing the following outputs for different inputs.

1. i/p : `"\\{testing}"` - o/p: `"{testing}"`
2. i/p : `"\\{\\{testing}}"` - o/p: `"{\\{testing}}"`
3. i/p : `"\\{\\{\\{testing}}}"` - o/p: `"{\\{\\{testing}}}"`

I want `"\"` should be removed from the passed i/p string, and all `"\\{"` should be replaced with `"{"`.

I feel the problem is with regex value i.e., `"\\\\{.*?\\\\}"`.

Can anyone let me know what should be the regex value to the get required o/p.

Comment: Why not just use something **replaceAll("\\", "")** you can just add other characters to it as well...

Comment: Are you passing as an input `"\\{testing}"` or `"\{testing}"`? The last one won't compile.

Comment: My outputs for your examples are:
`i/p: "\\{testing}" -  o/p: "\testing}"`
`i/p: "\\{\\{testing}}" - o/p: "\\{testing}}"`
`i/p: "\\{\\{\\{testing}}}" - o/p: "\\{\{testing}}}"`

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question however seems to me replaceAll will do it. Here is an example that will remove the characters '\', '|' and '/' **replaceAll("[\\\\]*[|]*[/]*", "")**

Comment: My last comment with outputs different to those you said, were with the regex shown before @Baz's edition: `"\\{.*?\\}"`. With the current regex (`"\\\\{.*?\\\\}"`) you get a `PatternSyntaxException`.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. Sorry, if I changed the content of the question somehow. Just wanted to improve the structure.

Comment: @Baz No, you didn't change the content. You only changed the way it's shown. It happens that adding the ` makes the escape char \ not to work. You made the code look correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Any reasons why you are not simply using [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)?

```
String noSlashes = input.replace("\\", "");
```

Or, if you need to remove backslashes only when they are before opening curly braces:

```
String noSlashes = input.replace("\\{", "{");
```

Comment: The method is generic method and I am using to escape different characters. I will build the regex value based on characters to be removed. Here my code is working only for 1st occurance not for others.

Comment: @user1073430 What I'm saying is that you seem to be rewriting a method that already exists. You can also use `replaceAll` if you want to use regex.

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as the following:

```
String result = remainingValue.replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's been answered before, if you only want to remove the slashes `\` before the `{`, the best way is just to use

```
String noSlashes = input.replace("\\{", "{");
```

But in your question you asked *Can anyone let me know what should be the regex value*. If you are using regular expressions because you want to remove the `\` not just before any `{`, but only in those `{` that are properly closed later with `}`, then the answer is: NO. [You can't match nested `{}` with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/1192381)

Answer (score -2):

Change the RegEx: `"\\&([^;]{6})"`

```
private String removeEscapeChars(String remainingValue) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\&([^;]{6})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(remainingValue);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String before = remainingValue.substring(0, matcher.start());
            String after = remainingValue.substring(matcher.start() + 1);
            remainingValue = (before + after);
        }
        return remainingValue;
    }
```

it should work..

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: This is the question Toto :): "How to remove escape characters from a string in JAVA ?"